ReactiveElasticsearchClient query composite aggregation not return all result
I use ReactiveElasticsearchClient to query composite aggregation but not return all result.
I mean I add all docCount value in return message manually, the result is not same as the document total number in the index.
And I suddenly found when I use two column as aggregation columns, the value are matched.
So I tried to increase the aggregation columns more and more and found until I use 10 columns as composite aggregation, it works fine. But when I use 11 columns as composite aggregation, the total docCount will be half of total document numbers...
Does ES have some limitation? Why it will reduce aggregation number without alert or warning which is very confused.


- Size -
The size parameter can be set to define how many composite buckets should be returned. Each composite bucket is considered as a single bucket, so setting a size of 10 will return the first 10 composite buckets created from the value sources. The response contains the values for each composite bucket in an array containing the values extracted from each value source. Defaults to 10.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html

Thanks @Murat K., but I could get more than 10 buckets, my problem is when I have more than 10 columns as composite field, the total docCount will be decrease. Like when I use 10 columns, it return 10000 docCount, but when it is 11 column, it return 5000 docCount...
